# Adding HEX character in a file using perl code

Tags: perl

I have to write perl code to enter hex character in file before "END OF REPORT" comtent in a file. I want to add 0D 0A 0C.

I am using following command to print this:

print"\x0c";

this is printing :0D 0A 0D 0A 0C

Kindly help.

Comment: I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: Please post the actual code and output, it's not possible to get the output you show from the code you provided.

Comment: `print "\x0C";` cannot possibly print `0D 0A 0D 0A 0C` or even the desired `0D 0A 0C`. It will print `0C` followed by whatever $\ contains.

Comment: @ikegami: Note that $\ is undefined by default.

Comment: @Keith Thompson, Indeed, but it acts as the empty string (no warning). I'll adjust.

Answer (score 3):

To print the desired `0D 0A 0C` on a binary handle:

```
print "\x0D\x0A\x0C";
```

To print the desired `0D 0A 0C` on a handle with the `:crlf` layer (default for Windows):

```
print "\n\x0C";
```

If `$\` was changed from its default (undef, which acts here as an empty string), you may have extra characters appended (but not prepended as you showed). You can temporarily undo that effect using the following just before the `print`:

```
local $\;
```